# MySQL MAX associated with a second column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the highest and lowest value associated with an account for a 1 year timeframe for a country. This data is pulled from one table.

I will have the highest account return for account one and lowest account return for account two for a country. So 1 result per country.

I've got the following but it doesn't work properly, it actually provides me the highest and lowest values from an incorrect account as it should only work with accounts that have 1 year timeframe as well.

Also forgot to add perhaps ordering the overall result by dpromo_one only do these countries eg country in ('united states','united kingdom','south africa','india','australia') for these selected countries only. Its just got quite complex that it went way over my head.

```
SELECT DISTINCT acc2.account_name AS account_one, acc5.account_name AS account_two,
    MAX( acc2.dpromo_rate ) AS dpromo_one, MIN( acc5.dpromo_rate ) AS dpromo_two,
    acc2.deposit_term, acc2.country
FROM accounts acc2
INNER JOIN accounts acc5 ON acc2.country = acc5.country
WHERE acc2.type =2
AND acc5.type =2
AND acc2.deposit_term =  '1 Year'
GROUP BY country
```

overall output example could be the following
 for line 1:

```
Country    Bank    Highest    Bank             Lowest
USA        BOFA 1yr     1%      Wells Fargo 1yr 0.5% 
UK        HSBC 1yr     0.5%    Halifax 1yr     0.25% 
Australia CBA  1yr     0.4%    NAB 1yr         0.1%
```

eg the accounts table has the following fields for example that are relevant

account_name
country
dpromo_rate
deposit_term

note that we are having both accounts and rates side by side. my code does this but incorrectly though and thats why it also explains why i have aliases for duplicate field names.

Comment: Which of the other fields being returned do you want? For example I presume that there are multiple account_names for a country yet due to the group by only one (and which is unspecified) will be returned. Could you post some sample data and what you would like to be output.

Comment: overall output example should be the following for line 1:   USA     BOFA   1%    Wells Fargo 0.5%     and line 2 could be UK    HSBC 0.5%    Halifax   0.25%   and line 3   Australia   CBA   0.4%    NAB 0.1%

Comment: And the input data to give that line?

Comment: Problem is that you're selecting non-grouped fields while using aggregate functions. In such a case, there's absolutely NO guarantee as to what records you'll be getting.

Answer (score 0):

It is doing *exactly* what MySQL says it will do.  Columns not included in the `group by` clause have arbitrary values.  In most other databases, the query would simply fail with a syntax error.

Here is a trick to get the names of the accounts:

```
SELECT substring_index(group_concat(acc2.account_name order by acc2.dpromo_rate desc), ',', 1) AS account_one,
       substring_index(group_concat(acc5.account_name order by acc5.dpromo_rate asc), ',', 1)  AS account_two,
       MAX( acc2.dpromo_rate ) AS dpromo_one, MIN( acc5.dpromo_rate ) AS dpromo_two,
       acc2.deposit_term, acc2.country
FROM accounts acc2
INNER JOIN accounts acc5 ON acc2.country = acc5.country
WHERE acc2.type =2 AND acc5.type =2 AND acc2.deposit_term =  '1 Year'
GROUP BY country
```

I think you can simplify the query to a simple aggregation.  I don't see why you are doing a join:

```
SELECT substring_index(group_concat(acc.account_name order by acc.dpromo_rate desc), ',', 1) AS account_one,
       substring_index(group_concat(acc.account_name order by acc.dpromo_rate asc), ',', 1)  AS account_two,
       MAX(acc.dpromo_rate) AS dpromo_one, MIN(acc.dpromo_rate) AS dpromo_two,
       acc.deposit_term, acc.country
FROM accounts acc
WHERE acc.type = 2 and acc.deposit_term =  '1 Year'
GROUP BY country;
```

If you intend for the deposit term to only apply to the `max`, then replace the max with:

```
max(case when acc.deposit_term =  '1 Year' then acc.dpromo_rate end) as dpromo_one
```

Comment: it was an oversight from previous code, i have revised the information about i hope it helps out

Comment: @JohnSmith . . . I removed it from my query.  Does this work for you?

Comment: unfortunately i get #1052 - Column 'dpromo_rate' in field list is ambiguous  , i have provided further information of the actual table structure(only relevant ones) to help. please look in original post

Comment: That is quite a neat way of doing it (as long as the account_name doesn't contain a comma)

Comment: for 2nd one I got the following error - - Unknown column 'acct.dpromo_rate' in 'field list'

Comment: @Kickstart . . . you can use a different separator if you want `substring_index(group_concat(acc.account_name separator '|' order by acct.dpromo_rate desc ), '|', 1)`.

Comment: for 1st one i got #1054 - Unknown column 'acct2.dpromo_rate' in 'field list'

Comment: +50 Gordon for your solutions, thanks for the time and effort you put in figuring out the best query

Answer (score 0):

I thing this will give result

```
select max(dpromo_rate), min(dpromo_rate), country, account_name, provider from accounts 
where deposit_term = '1 Year' group by country, provider, account_name
```

Answer (score 0):

To give you the basics in your output example:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT z.county, b.account_name, b.dpromo_rate, d.account_name, d.dpromo_rate
FROM accounts z
INNER JOIN (SELECT country, type, MAX(dpromo_rate) AS MaxRate FROM accounts WHERE type = 2 AND deposit_term =  '1 Year' GROUP BY country, type) a
ON z.country = a.country AND z.type = a.type
INNER JOIN accounts b
ON a.country = b.country and a.MaxRate = b.dpromo_rate AND a.type = b.type
INNER JOIN (SELECT country, type, MIN(dpromo_rate) AS MinRate FROM accounts WHERE type = 2 AND deposit_term =  '1 Year' GROUP BY country, type) c
ON z.country = c.country AND z.type = c.type
INNER JOIN accounts d
ON c.country = d.country and c.MinRate = d.dpromo_rate AND c.type = d.type
```

This is just getting the country, account name with the max rate, the actual max rate, account name with the min rate and the actual min rate.

Not sure where deposit term and provider are wanted in the output, but they would be easy to get from the b or d alias tables.

Note that that this will make a mess should you have multiple accounts in a country which all share the max or min rates.

To limit it to a few countries and order by the max rate:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT z.county, b.account_name, b.dpromo_rate, d.account_name, d.dpromo_rate
FROM accounts z
INNER JOIN (SELECT country, type, MAX(dpromo_rate) AS MaxRate FROM accounts WHERE type = 2 AND deposit_term =  '1 Year' GROUP BY country, type) a
ON z.country = a.country AND z.type = a.type
INNER JOIN accounts b
ON a.country = b.country and a.MaxRate = b.dpromo_rate AND a.type = b.type
INNER JOIN (SELECT country, type, MIN(dpromo_rate) AS MinRate FROM accounts WHERE type = 2 AND deposit_term =  '1 Year' GROUP BY country, type) c
ON z.country = c.country AND z.type = c.type
INNER JOIN accounts d
ON c.country = d.country and c.MinRate = d.dpromo_rate AND c.type = d.type
WHERE z.country IN ('united states', 'united kingdom', 'south africa', 'india', 'australia')
ORDER BY b.dpromo_rate
```

To limit it to one per country then you can do this:-

```
SELECT z.county, b.account_name, b.dpromo_rate, d.account_name, d.dpromo_rate
FROM accounts z
INNER JOIN (SELECT country, type, MAX(dpromo_rate) AS MaxRate FROM accounts WHERE type = 2 AND deposit_term =  '1 Year' GROUP BY country, type) a
ON z.country = a.country AND z.type = a.type
INNER JOIN accounts b
ON a.country = b.country and a.MaxRate = b.dpromo_rate AND a.type = b.type
INNER JOIN (SELECT country, type, MIN(dpromo_rate) AS MinRate FROM accounts WHERE type = 2 AND deposit_term =  '1 Year' GROUP BY country, type) c
ON z.country = c.country AND z.type = c.type
INNER JOIN accounts d
ON c.country = d.country and c.MinRate = d.dpromo_rate AND c.type = d.type
WHERE z.country IN ('united states', 'united kingdom', 'south africa', 'india', 'australia')
GROUP BY z.county
ORDER BY b.dpromo_rate
```

Note that if 2 accounts in a country have the same rate which is the highest rate for that country then only one will be returned. Which one that is returned is not certain.

Comment: please note you have missed out on my code above .....   AND acc2.deposit_term =  '1 Year'   , this is what makes those unique...could you check out the original post as i have added further  to help out

Comment: Edited to add the additional checks

Comment: actually it works, thanks for that, i wonder if we could sort the data by the overall result by highest dpromo_one and to only do these countries eg country in ('united states','united kingdom','south africa','india','australia') for these selected countries.

Comment: also the result need to be grouped by the country as i am seeing the same countries because sometimes some banks have the exact highest amounts or the exact lowest amounts. eg just pick 1 highest result?

Comment: Edited to add a sort and limit it by country

Comment: That is an issue I pointed out originally, but I need to know which of the highest or lowest you want to chose. Or you could bodge it by using GROUP BY z.country at the end of the query rather than using DISTINCT (but which one of 2 equal maxes that is returned will be undefined)

Comment: it is fine with me as long i have only 1 result for highest and lowest so if either has multiple results i am fine if it removes the duplicates at random.

Comment: actually the third example is exactly what i require, although it is ordering from least deposit to highest. Could i have it in reverse, a simple DESC at the end?

Comment: in anycase its basically done now, not sure if this is the most efficient way to handle this query but your 3rd option above actually works exactly how i need it to so +100 for you. Great work

Comment: You can just add DESC for descending for the order by